# What are some options for sending text messages to voip phones using Cisco CallManager?

Tags: .net, cisco

Our client (a hospital) has a bank of Cisco voip handsets that are checked out at the start of each shift. They would like our software (clinical messaging) to send a text alert to one of their handsets. This is a one way informational message - two way communication isn't required. Our application is on the Microsoft tech stack.

The handset model is 7925.

Comment: depends, what handsets are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you are running a 7925G handsets and CUCM 8.0 or higher. These devices accept [Cisco's XML Object](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/all_models/xsi/8_0_1/xmlobjectsref.html) model which can be used for a range of functionality including displaying text messages on the devices. Below is an example from Cisco documentation of what you might use to display a message on the device. ([Table 3-1 has info on device support](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/all_models/xsi/8_0_1/xsidevguide.pdf))

```
<CiscoIPPhoneText>
  <Title>Title text goes here</Title>
  <Prompt>The prompt text goes here</Prompt>
  <Text>Text to display as the message body goes here</Text>
</CiscoIPPhoneText>
```

You can create this message using .NETs HttpWebClient class. Make sure you check the documentation regarding which HTTP version you should and other specifics you might need for the communication to work. Hope that helps.